# Changes after graduation

Tags: discussion

Background:

In a discussion elsewhere about graduation I read that after graduation the number of users on Mathematica Stack Exchange will increase significantly ( Leonid called it rapid expansion ).

Considering that:

1) If I do a search on a Mathematica related issue a Stack Exchange question will be listed in the first 20, ( if not 10 ) results;

2) The beta is not closed;

3) Searching for help from more experienced, knowledgeable ( smarter, if you like ) peers is strongly encouraged in the mathematics community;

I ( therefore ) think pre- and post-beta statistics, of the other Stack Sites are not applicable to Mathematica. So, I think that after 'graduation' things will stay more or less the same.

**Question: What will =noticeably= change after graduation, for the site, for the moderator(s), experts and users ?**

Comment: I disagree with Leonid on that one. It is possible that we see an increase in the number of new users/low quality questions around or after graduation, because generally graduation occurs only when the traffic is rising (i.e., more people are finding us through Google) and when traffic rises, maintaining quality becomes harder. However, graduation status has nothing to do with it. He probably might've meant that staying in beta => lower rep for privileges => more regulars to tackle/close/delete the crud, which I agree with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One obvious change is that people with Reputation of at least 200, but less than 20000 will lose privileges (the lowest priviledge with different required reputation for beta and graduated, *retag questions*, has 200 required reputation on beta, but 500 on non-beta, while the highest, *trusted user*, has 4000 for beta, but 20000 for graduated).

Another obvious change is that the sites design will be changed from the beta design to a final design.

A third change, which probably will affect the number of users who find this site, is that, if I understand it correctly, it will be listed at the bottom of all pages on each other graduated site (esp. Stack Overflow, math.SE and physics.SE).