# How should we mark our graduation (and how should we prepare for it)?

Tags: discussion

We have recently [learned](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5039798#5039798) that the site will graduate soon. That means we will soon have a [nice new design](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/what-should-our-site-design-look-like), [higher rep thresholds to do things](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/440/8), and a reason to celebrate.

- Should we try to do some more promotion of the site to coincide with graduation?
- Are there any events, "question parties" or other ways to celebrate that we should consider?
- Does it make sense to get the [blog](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/419/8) up and running to coincide with launch, or should it wait a few days?
- Given that there will be fewer users with high privileges, how should we handle sharing the load of cleaning up after graduation? Are there intermediate users we should be mentoring/encouraging to step up?

Comment: I am adding multiple answers for specific things we should do to prepare and celebrate. Please upvote those you agree with and downvote those you don't, and feel free to add your own ideas, one per answer.

Comment: We may publish an advertisement in all big uni's portals **"Hey! come to do your Mma homework with us!"** ... uhhh wait ... I was joking

Comment: @belisarius, but we *could* make a homework party for a day or so.. Just to skrew with all the teachers who have then the oportunity to think about new excercises ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I think having the first blog post when we graduate is a very good idea. It serves as a way of announcing ourselves to the world (again!).

Comment: Regarding the blog, it's time to start writing posts even if we don't have the blog technically set up yet.  [We got the green light for it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4948330#4948330) but it seems it's taking a while to set up the technical side of things ... writing posts takes a bit of time, so why not start now?

Comment: @Szabolcs That's a good point. Any thoughts on what we should say in the inaugural post?

Answer (score 9):

One thing I would like us to consider is making sure we have all the main [tag wikis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags) in good shape. I will go through some of them when I have time, and adding extracts at the very least.

Comment: I could add here that it takes just 50 tag wiki edits to get the silver Research Assistent badge. ;-)

Comment: @Sjoer, Verbeia: I am working on this, but there are so many underdefined, confusing or senseless tags, that it is a huge undertaking. I soon will post a largish meta question about merging/deleting of some tags to prompt some community reflections.

Answer (score 9):

We should also consider changing the [community promotion ad on other sites to reflect whatever the new design might be](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/8). And of course if people can come up with a better slogan... :-)

Comment: Mathematica, the erotica exotica

Answer (score 4):

We may also want to consider a concerted effort at answering [currently unanswered questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

For example, I've just done [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7183/8), which was over a month old.

Answer (score 4):

The [FAQ text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) is still the same it was when the site was created.  It needs to be updated and finalized.  [Here's the discussion thread for it.](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/what-should-our-faq-contain)  Feel free to edit my draft text there.